# How to add an include directory based on environment variable in RHIDE without expansion?

Tags: c++, redhawksdr

The REDHAWK IDE insists on expanding environment variables when creating the `Makefile.am.ide` file. For example, assume that `$SRC_ROOT` is `/srcpath` and I add an include path in the `Path and Symbols` window of the C/C++ section of my project as below:

```
${env_var:SRC_ROOT}/include
```

the generated `Makefile.am.ide` file contains:

```
rehawk_INCLUDES_auto = -I/srcpath/include
```

when what I really want is:

```
rehawk_INCLUDES_auto = -I$(SRC_ROOT)/include
```

This is important because this file is used by other team members that have different values for `$SRC_ROOT`. Currently we have to put the include path in `Makefile.am`, but then the IDE doesn't see the header files in the directory and sees errors for the code referred to in the missing headers.

Is there anyway to get RHIDE, to not expand the environment variables when it generates `Makefile.am.ide`?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for but you can always disable the auto-updates of the Makefile.am.ide by disabling the REDHAWK C++ auto-inclusion builder. This is in the projects properties in the Builders section.

This will allow you to add to Eclipse's Paths and Symbols section without the auto-inclusion builder picking it up and adding it to your Makefile.am.ide.

If you do choose to disable this builder you will then need to manage the addition of new source files on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Youssef's answer is not a bad one, but I've come up with a different way to work around the problem. In `Makefile.am`, override the `redhawk_INCLUDES_auto` value to be what I what it to be:

```
include $(srcdir)/Makefile.am.ide

#Override the value from Makefile.am.ide that may be wrong!
override redhawk_INCLUDES_auto = -I$(SRC_ROOT)/include
```

This requires one to update any custom include directories in both the IDE and the `Makefile.am` file, but managing the source files is still automatic.

It still has the issue that the `Makefile.am.ide` file's contents will be different for other developers which complicates version control. So I don't consider this be a complete answer to the problem.